# Disable internalization (i18n) for public folder in NextJS

Tags: javascript, next.js, internationalization

I thought of increasing performance in my NextJS V12 project. By changing domain language change switcher towards sub-path language switcher. Since it won't have to do a page reload. Found out, that NextJS already provices i18n functionality, just had to tweak `next.config.js` file.

However, I came to the point where it also tries to access images folder with the specified locale. To just give perspective, I only added three language locales inside `next.config.js` file:

```
locales: ['nl', 'en', 'ru'],
defaultLocale: 'nl',
localeDetection: false,
```

Due to fact, that nl locale can be reached by page of `/`, it finds static images folder in `images/...`. However, whenever I use different locale than the default one (let's pick 'en' for this example), it searches for `en/images/...` folder. I don't have and do not want to structure like that (content isn't related with any specific words to the given locale)

Are there any workarounds regarding disabling static assets search by locales towards just accessing static assets?

`NextJS @12`